# UnityPlayerActivity onCreateが呼ばれない

Tags: android, unity3d

UnityPlayerActivityからonCreateが呼ばれません。
原因をご存知のかたいらっしゃいましたらご教授下さい。

jar

```
package a.b.c;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class testActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("UnityPlayerActivity", "Call onCreate");
    }
}
```

unity AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="a.b.c" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="a.b.c.testActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

起動時に呼ばれるActivityがUnityPlayerActivityのため
testActivity#onCreateが呼ばれていないようです。

AndroidManifest.xmlの

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
```

を

```
<activity android:name="a.b.c.testActivity"
```

と変更することで、起動時にtestActivity#onCreateは呼ばれるかと思います。